# Swift struct extension by protocol

Tags: swift, struct, extension-methods, swift-protocols

I have a simple struct to group some strings

```
struct MyStruct {
    static let bar = "BAR"
    static let foo = "FOO"
}
```

`MyStruct.bar` will return the string `BAR`

I want to add more properties to each item in the struct. Like:

`MyStruct.bar.desc` should return some custom description about the `MyStruct` item `bar`.

Can we extend the struct like an enum? Something like:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var desc:String { get }
}

extension MyProtocol where <No idea> { //where Self: RawRepresentable in Enum-case
    var desc: String {
        return "Custom description" //Based on the struct item
    }
}
```

So that, `struct MyStruct:MyProtocol {..` should work.

**Note**: I have N number of structs like `MyStruct`. So, I don't want to implement the custom properties inside each struct individually.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an `enum` for this purpose? It seems much better suited to your goals than a struct with static properties.

Comment: You are right. Enums serves well in this case. I have used a plain string (literal type) for the demonstration purpose. My actual use case is something different. I can't rely with enums since they support the literals only.

Comment: You should describe what problem you are trying to solve. That is, _the_ problem for which you showed us your "solution" which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
```

With a default value for `desc`

```
extension MyProtocol {
    var desc: String { "Custom description" /*Based on the struct item*/ }
}
```

And add it to your structs like

```
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {}
```

See https://replit.com/@Dev1an/Swift-protocol-extension for a more advanced version

Comment: This is useful. This adds a custom property to the struct object itself. But I want to add custom properties to its items. MyStruct().<item>.desc is what Im looking for.

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you want exactly, I think you can accomplish that using protocols and KeyPaths (see my updated example on [replit](https://replit.com/@Dev1an/Swift-protocol-extension)). Please provide a better example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you you want to be able to write `MyStruct().<item>.desc` I would suggest you take a look at [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible):

> Types that conform to the CustomStringConvertible protocol can provide their own representation to be used when converting an instance to a string.

I'm not sure why bar is static since it seems you want a property so I added a `baz` property of type `Baz`:

```
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol, CustomStringConvertible { // or you can make `MyProtocol` inherit from CustomStringConvertible
    struct Baz: CustomStringConvertible {
        let qux = "QUX"
        var description: String {
            qux
        }
    }
    static let bar = "BAR"
    static let foo = "FOO"
    let baz = Baz()
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype Item: CustomStringConvertible
    associatedtype OtherItem: CustomStringConvertible
    static var bar: Item { get }
    var baz: OtherItem { get }
}


extension MyProtocol where Self: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return print(String(describing: baz)
    }
}

print(String(describing: MyStruct.bar)) // prints "BAR"
print(String(describing: MyStruct()) // prints "QUX"
```